# Why is my linear gradient not working properly over my background image? (rails and sass)

Tags: css, sass

I have an background image which I am trying to get a linear gradient to display over. I've checked a few other questions and none of those answers seem to do it for me. so far I have this...

```
    .bottom-pic
        width: 100%
        height: 425px
        background-image: url("bottom-img-3.png")
        background-size: cover
        background-repeat: no-repeat
        background-position: 0 -255px
        position: relative

      .overlay
          background: linear-gradient(-180deg, #20202C 34%, rgba(32,32,44,0.00) 81%, #20202C 100%)
```

My gradient is still not showing up though.

Comment: What is the problem? Is the gradient not showing? Or the image? Or is something else not what you expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your element can only have one background image. As the background image is already given by the url, the rest would be ignored.

To overlay your image, you will need to place an additional DIV element within your element that has the background image set and apply a gradient background there. Of course you need to make sure, the contained element has the same width and height as its parent.

Comment: This won't work, gradients have to be as `background` or `background-image`

Comment: Just checked it out, you are right, changing the answer

Answer (score 0):

depends which browser you / your visitors are using - you need to use prefixes for some of them, like `-webkit-linear-gradient...` etc.

Here's a tool that can help with those prefixes on gradients:
http://www.css3factory.com/linear-gradients/

or this one (more general for CSS prefixes): http://output.jsbin.com/gufoko/quiet